# c# windows not converting some emoji

Tags: c#, .net, windows, emoji

in the Net level emoji code is directly converted to the black and White emoji

```
example
when .Net Received
:punch: converted to converted to 
:+1:converted to converted to 
:-1:converted to converted to
```

and these are on convert on system level we received directly black and White emoji

but some emoji not converted with the different name... and so how can I add this on the system level that these emoji also convert with the different name.. because some platform sends :+1: and some send :thumbsup: ?

```
these emoji not converted
:facepunch: Not converted to converted to 
:thumbsup: Not converted to converted to 
:thumbsdown:converted to converted to
```

These are the same emoji with different name and all these emoji converted on another platform like android,ios

Answer (score 2):

> in the Net level emoji code is directly converted to the black and White emoji

there's no such thing as the "Net level". You deal with strings that contain unicode codepoints; how these are rendered is a totally different affair.

You're not mentioning what software does this, but I assure you that .Net doesn't take your string containing `:emoji:` and convert it to a single unicode codepoint. That's the job of whatever you use to enter these strings, or it is the job of whatever takes these strings and renders them.

At any rate, it's not a bug that a text console doesn't convert `:squirtgun:` to a picture of a squirt gun.

So, go wild. Build your own `:emoji:` conversion routines. It's a moving target.